# Font looks thicker (white color with dark background) in web page

Tags: css, fonts, dreamweaver, photoshop, frontend

Got a question for the font named Rockwell Std Light. I used in Photoshop to show the white text with blue background, and also did the same thing in Dreamweaver. However, the font always looks thicker in the web page. Does anyone have idea what issue may be here? The web page is just very basic DIV and CSS background color setting.

Thank you in advance.

[Picture-Compare with Photoshop & Dreamweaver](http://www.evernote.com/shard/s87/sh/a45e0aed-66bf-4129-9b0c-c538b9a8a398/38ce69fe4908556e94f19d5a6129a712/res/994f949f-f8d5-4382-88bf-704b5255eb49/Screen+shot+2011-06-07+at+11.37.11+PM.png)

Comment: Are they images in the web page or just text?

Comment: it's just a text in web page. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @joakimdahlstrom said different applications render fonts differently, Photoshop also has additional effects such as smoothing etc.

In general however, you should not use a font such as Rockwell Std Light on a web page as it isn't a "web safe font" i.e. not everyone has this font installed on their system so those that don't won't see it. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_websafe_fonts.asp for some common ones.

You have a few options for non-standard fonts if you want cross-browser / system compatibility:

1. Save the text as an image in Photoshop and include it in your web page as an image (making sure to specify the alt text)
2. Use a service such as [TypeKit](http://typekit.com)

TypeKit doesn't have the Rockwell font, so you'd be better going down the image route if you definitely want to use that font.

Answer (score 1):

Applications, operating systems etc. render fonts differently. There's nothing you can do about it.